Excel VBA code to Sum the debit up values when credit happen
I'm having excel sheet with debit transaction and Credit transaction in specific dates, I want VBA code to sum the previous debit transaction when Credit transaction occur and reconcile the amount if the credit amount greater than total previous amount the result be zero if false the result be unsettled amount and it belong to which date and this action restart again when credit transaction happens again but not taking the previous settled ones.
I tried all ordinary excel function but no result I believe the answer in VBA but is not my specialty.

Here are sample of data and the expected result highlighted in yellow for more clarification the debit transaction represent the accrued interest of the previous month


Can you provide sample data and expected result?

Here are sample of data and the expected result highlighted in yellow for more clarification the debit transaction represent  the accrued interest of the previous month

Pls. in the future if you improve your post do it  directly in it, not in the comments.

Why not provide in text form so we can use; instead of having to type all this? Also, on 31-01-2023, we had accumulated debit of 4,243,794, but we already paid 12,355,000 of it; where did the 964,249 unsettled debit come from?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Aside from that: you haven't shown any work - you only posted a set of requirements and then left everything up to the Community. Please read [ask] and then edit to provide a [mcve]
